# symfony easyadmin customize field value

Tags: php, field, customization, symfony-3.4, easyadmin

i have an Entity Product that has a field category.
If i call the list i want to show the name of the Category.
If i call edit i want to show the name and the id of the Category in the Options like this

```
<select>
<option value=<?= $category->getId()?> ><?= $category->getName().' '.$category->getId() ?></option>
</select>
```

thats my configuration
//product.yml

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Product:
            class: CoreBundle\Entity\Product
            label: 'admin.entities.product.label'
            help: 'admin.entities.product.help'
            role: ROLE_ADMIN
            disabled_actions:
                - 'new'
                - 'delete'
           
            list:
                title: 'admin.entities.product.list.label'
                actions:
                    -
                        name: 'configureProduct'
                        icon: 'bolt'
                        label: 'admin.entities.product.actions.configure'
                fields:
                   
                    -
                        property: category
                        label: 'admin.entities.product.list.fields.category'

            edit:
                title: 'admin.entities.product.edit.label'
                fields:
                 
                    -
                        property: category
                        label: 'admin.entities.product.edit.fields.category'
```

How can do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.